# R/exams: Duplicated images in PDF files

Tags: r, r-exams

When using several R/exams exercises with TikZ plots, I have no problems generating exams in HTML format or for Canvas. However, exactly the same exercises when rendered to PDF show the same plots in different questions. As a simple example, you can use the same exercise twice, e.g., for the [automaton](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/automaton/) exercise shipped with the package:

```
library("exams")
set.seed(0)
exams2pdf(c("automaton.Rnw", "automaton.Rnw"))
```

The automaton diagram in the exercise should have a double circle for "A" (the "accepting state" described in the text). However, it has the double circle for "B" (as in the first exercise).

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EfOsLwmJU6rPx1eSQ8ruidxmcztgkrmK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The duplicated plot/graph is in the question body. No problem with plots in the solution/answer part.

Comment: Second question:
\begin{question}
Considera ... $s(0)=0$.. es:

\begin{center}
<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
include_tikz(gVelocidades[s], library = c("arrows"),width="5cm")
@
\end{center}
Indica .............
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide, results=tex>>=
answerlist(questions)
@
\end{question}
Third question:
\begin{question}
Considera ......
\begin{center}
<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
include_tikz(gPosiciones[s], library = c("arrows"),width="5cm")
@
\end{center}
Indica ..........
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide, results=tex>>=
answerlist(questions)
@
\end{question}

Comment: Thanks for posting the image. This is not reproducible for us, though. Please include the source code for a **minimal** simple exercise (either Rnw or Rmd is fine) in your question text plus the R code to generate the output from it.

Comment: Hhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1p2kc0N6wX3A3hRJyIwGKe3ZlRQfCO66G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The R file with two items.

Comment: As a quick note: The issue arises when two separate exercises generate a graphics file with the same name. This does not matter in most `exams2xyz` interfaces but it does in `exams2pdf`. A simple workaround is to use `include_tikz(..., name = ...)`  and use different names for the graphics from the different exercises. I'll try to dig deeper to avoid the problem altogether and then post a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks professor Achim! I already check that solution and It works. I don't how to declare my initial question is solved/anwered, someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was caused by generating graphics files with the same name in different exercises. Since exams 2.3-5 `exams2pdf()` had a workaround for resolving these problems but the workaround failed in some situations. I just fixed the problem in version 2.4-0.

Other workarounds include using different names for the TikZ graphics files via `include_tikz(..., name = ...)` or including the TikZ code as LaTeX in `exams2pdf`. For the latter the [logic.Rnw](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/logic/) template contains a worked example that embeds the LaTeX code (rather than generating a graphics file) for `exams2nops()` output.

Comment: Professor Achim...thanks for taking "R-exams" so seriously!